# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError Ror4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

Upgrading an older rails app to 4.2.10.  I am using the sorcery Gem. The app worked fine in RoR 3.2.8

Line 45 ---> @user = User.new(params[:user])

Extracted source (around line #45):

```
      # POST /users.json
       def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])

         respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save



  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

def create method

```
def create
       @user = User.new(params[:user])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            format.html { render action: "thanks", notice: 'User was 
    successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, 
location: @user }
          else
             format.html { render action: "new" }
             format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: 
 :unprocessable_entity }
         end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails 4 or later you need to use strong parameter as below

```
def permit_user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :etc)
end
```

and use this permitted parameter as

```
def create
       @user = User.new(permit_user_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            format.html { render action: "thanks", notice: 'User was 
    successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, 
location: @user }
          else
             format.html { render action: "new" }
             format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: 
 :unprocessable_entity }
         end
        end
      end
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Now I get the error;
NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `activation_token=' for #<User:0x00007f6fd4eb4e20>

Comment: can I see error log as I am unable find issue in user controller.

Comment: trace too long for comment by 8k.
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mWqAuMEs)

Comment: : Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2018-03-23 13:09:24.1557 15932/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1242 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2018-03-23 13:09:24.1560 15932/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:252 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2018-03-23 13:09:24.2039 15932/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:977 ]: Passenger core online, PID 15932

App 15951 stdout: 
App 15967 stdout: 
App 15975 stdout: 
[ N 2018-03-23 13:15:19.6056 15932/T3 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 15975, application /home/david/geofly (development)

Comment: you can share your log same as you share your user controller, I just need to look into root of cause

Comment: Now I am getting: Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
but, when I run this I get
Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists
/home/david/geofly/db/migrate/20180323142912_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

I tried dropping the db and trying again, here is terminal output.
[mysql-errors](https://pastebin.com/CHUV3rLv)

Comment: latest development.log

[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0aiYPSz8)

the ip is incorrect for the server. The previous issue was with SendGrid. The user was created, but the activation email was not sent, so the user already existed in create, but was not activated. Then this came up and I have not been able to get back to configuring SendGrid.

Comment: It's so much confusing now, can you post new question with issues you faced.